# Protege Ontop reasoner initialization [error]

Tags: protege

I would like to use Ontop SPARQL query, but whenever I select the OnTop reasoner, there is an error:

error during reasoning initialization: [...] abox requires exactly 1 data source in your OBDA model.    [image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't added the datasource into your protege, that's why this error happened.

> Step 1:  Go to `'Window'` tab -> `'Tab'` -> click on `'Ontop Mapping'`
>
> Step 2:  Inside Ontop Mapping window, click on `'Datasource manager'`
>   then fill in the requirement

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not the first one to face this problem. A quick Google found this page detailing the modes in which OntoP can be configured: https://github.com/ontop/ontop/wiki/Ontop-Preferences